# TokBox API doesn't work with an S3?

Tags: android, opentok, videochat, tokbox

Has anyone implemented the TokBox API?
It doesn't seems to work on an S3.

I am using S3 and iPhone.
It works fine on two iPhones but not between my S3 and an iPhone?

The sample code can be found at [here](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-android-sdk-demo)

in the above code sample

this is called

```
@Override
public void onSessionConnected() {
}
```

**means session is connected**

but

```
@Override
public void onPublisherStreamingStarted() {
    Log.i(LOGTAG, "publisher is streaming!");
}
```

or

```
@Override
public void onPublisherException(OpentokException exception) {
    Log.i(LOGTAG, "publisher failed! " + exception.toString());
}
```

this never be called

That means my video publishing is not started.

Comment: have you tried something? if yes add code here else try something.

Comment: @shailesh: why is that edit coming from a new account? Stick to one account, it works better for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your iPhone and S3 are both using the flash SDK and that they are both connected to the same session ID.

Comment: I am using the openTok sdk [@Github](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-android-sdk). What it the flash SDK? please clear.

Comment: In the sample code
 '@Override
    public void onSessionConnected() {
}'

        Log.i(LOGTAG, "session connected");

Comment: the iOS SDK comes in two flavors: opentok-ios-sdk is flash, and opentok-ios-sdk-webrtc is WebRTC. the Android SDK only comes in flash. so in order to get streams to work across, use the opentok-ios-sdk on iOS and the regular opentok-android-sdk on Android. before you run, make sure you also generate a new Session ID.